# how to get coverage report as jacocoTestReport.xml in React project

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I am using jenkins pipeline for my React project to with test, build and deploy steps.

I integrated sonarqube with my project. But sonar's jacoco doesn't assess my coverage report which is in generic coverage format(test-report.xml)

Is there a way to get my report as "jacocoTestReport.xml" in my React project without using maven or gradle. I couldn't find any document or 3rd party tools?

My related pipeline script:

```
sh '''
   ${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner \
   -Dsonar.projectKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
   -Dsonar.sources=. \
   -Dsonar.sources=. \
   -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=test-report.xml \
   -Dsonar.testExecutionReportPaths=test-report.xml \
   -Dsonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info \
   -Dsonar.coverageReportPaths=test-report.xml \
   -Dsonar.host.url=https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
   -Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxx
'''
```

The related error is like:

```
: Sensor Generic Coverage Report
INFO: Parsing /var/jenkins_home/workspace/**********/test-report.xml
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 36.948s
INFO: Final Memory: 49M/690M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: Error during parsing of the generic coverage report '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/*******/test-report.xml'. Look at SonarQube documentation to know the expected XML format.
ERROR: Caused by: Unknown XML node, expected "coverage" but got "testExecutions" at line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are only building a react application, hence that it is just JavaScript/TypeScript and my answer is based on that assumption.

If that is the case you can simply ignore the `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` property. You are already providing that information via the `lcov.info` file. Sonarqube will be able to read the coverage information from this file.

Furthermore the `test-report.xml` normally only contains a list of the executed tests and their outcome. You will normally find no kind of coverage information in there. Therefore your build might also break on the `sonar.coverageReportPaths` property (my suggestion is also to remove that one).